# JavaScript exporting Telerik Grid false

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik-grid, radgrid

I am adding an export to excel feature to an already existing (and functional) web page.

The JavaScript to export my RadGrid:

```
function onRequestStart(sender, args) {
    if (isExporting) {
        args.set_enableAjax(false);
    }
}

function exportToExcel(sender, args) {
    console.log("Made it here!");

    isExporting = true;

    var masterTable = $find('<%= MyGrid.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView();
    console.log(masterTable);
    masterTable.exportToExcel();
    console.log(masterTable.exportToExcel());

    isExporting = false;
}
```

The RadGrid that is created comes from a separate JS file, so not sure what to show here except for the radgrid creation line I guess. The file that all of this code exists in is a .aspx file.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="MyGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" Height="100%" AllowSorting="true">
    <ClientSettings EnablePostBackOnRowClick="false>
        <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" UseStaticHeaders="true" />
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
        <ClientEvents OnCommand="function(sender,args) { myLibrary.mainGrid.onGridCommand(sender, args) }"
                      OnRowDataBound="function(sender,args) { mylibrary.mainGrid.onRowDatabound(sender,args) }"
                      OnRowClick="function(sender,args) { mylibrary.mainGrid.onRowClick(sender,args) }"
                      onRowMouseOut="function(sender,args) { mylibrary.mainGrid.onRowMouseOut(sender,args)}"/>
    </ClientSettings>
    <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="None" ClientDataKeyNames="Cant share these :)" TableLayout="Auto" 
                     AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20">
        ... fill out table with <NoRecordsTemplate>, <PagerStyle>, <Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

The issue:

When my function gets called I log stuff to see what happens on the inside...

- I see the "Made it Here!"
- I see the masterTable variable get filled with data that seems correct. Main thing here Im guessing is the portion of it labeled _dataSource and _dataItems.
- Then I see a false for the value for masterTable.exportToExcel();

Why is the false being shown for a variable that seems to contain the important information?

Comment: It's not really mentioned [here](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/client-side-programming/gridtableview-object/methods/exporttoexcel-) what the return value of exportToExcel should be.  In the demo pages, it seems that the method triggers the download of the excel file.  The demo pages' code does not pay attention to the return value of exportToExcel.

Comment: No download is being triggered aswell, I do not see anything in downloads, documents nor in the project itself. Just a bit lost on where to turn due to my lack of familiarity with JS @James